# Getting data from FullCalendar using external dragging

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

EDIT: Made a Codebin showing the issue: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqoy2/3
TL;DR: After dragging one or more events to calendar and clicking the save button, I want to output correctly formatted JSON that can actually be used.

In the demo of fullcalendar-2.6.1 external dragging (http://fullcalendar.io/download/ in the external-dragging.html) I've been trying to access the data of the events being dragged into the calendar.

I tried using the suggested:

```
$("#save").click(function() {
var eventsFromCalendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
var eventsJson = JSON.stringify(eventsFromCalendar);
```

however, eventsJson outputs the following error: 
TypeError: cyclic object value

I found a way to bypass the error by using the following code instead:

```
seen = [];

var eventsJson = JSON.stringify(eventsFromCalendar, function (key, val) {
   if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
       if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
           return;
       }
       seen.push(val);
   }
   return val;
});
```

With one event, this will output the following:

```
[{
    "title":"My Event 3",
    "start":"2016-03-15",
    "end":null,
    "_id":"_fc5",
    "className":[],
    "allDay":true,
    "_allDay":true,
    "_start":"2016-03-15",
    "_end":null,
    "source":{"events":[null]}
}]
```

Choosing two events will output the following:

```
    [{
        "title": "My Event 3",
        "start": "2016-03-23",
        "end": "2016-03-25",
        "_id": "_fc7",
        "className": [],
        "allDay": true,
        "_allDay": true,
        "_start": "2016-03-23",
        "_end": "2016-03-25",
        "source":
            {
                "events": [null, {
                    "title": "My Event 4",
                    "start": "2016-03-23",
                    "end": "2016-03-25",
                    "_id": "_fc13",
                    "className": [],
                    "allDay": true,
                    "_allDay": true,
                    "_start": "2016-03-23",
                    "_end": "2016-03-25"
                }]
            }
    }, null]
```

Doing it with 3 events will output the following:

```
[{
"title": "My Event 2",
"start": "2016-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
"end": null,
"_id": "_fc2",
"className": [],
"allDay": true,
"_allDay": true,
"_start": "2016-03-27T00:00:00.000Z",
"_end": null,
"source": {
    "events": [null,
        {
            "title": "My Event 4",
            "start": "2016-03-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": null,
            "_id": "_fc7",
            "className": [],
            "allDay": true,
            "_allDay": true,
            "_start": "2016-03-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            "_end": null
        },
        {
            "title": "My Event 5",
            "start": "2016-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "end": null,
            "_id": "_fc10",
            "className": [],
            "allDay": true,
            "_allDay": true,
            "_start": "2016-04-04T00:00:00.000Z",
            "_end": null
        }]
}
}, null, null]
```

As you can see, something goes wrong when it constructs the object. I'm not sure what the source: {"events":[null]} is supposed to be, but it may be the cause of the error. I'm also not sure what the difference between the start and _start and end and _end is.

Hope you can help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you prepare a demo illustrating your issue in something like jsfiddle or codebin?

Comment: Yeah, you got it. http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqoy2/3

Comment: I guess you want to send that JSON to a page where you save it, isn't it? Why not creating your own object, and storing only wanted values after each `drop` event, than saving only when you click `#save` button?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using ASP.NET MVC so I need to send it to a controller, but I need it to be sent on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code above, and because I dislike js, work with it in whatever your back end language is.

For me I used the following in php

```
$object = json_decode($request->request->get('hoursArray')[0]);
$myHours =[];
for($i=0;$i<count($object);$i++){
    if ($i==0){
        $myHours[$i]['title'] = $object[0]->title;
        $myHours[$i]['date'] = $object[0]->start;
     }else{
        $myHours[$i]['title'] = $object[0]->source->events[$i]->title;
        $myHours[$i]['date'] = $object[0]->source->events[$i]->start;
     }
}
```